# How to fix update problems with debian 9?

Tags: linux, debian, repository, gpg

I had debian jessie installed and just perform an update with the command:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

The problem is that I upgrade to version 9 of debian and now when I run the same command to update (debian9) it throws me errors of public keys, repository not found or unsigned.

Is there any way to get back to version 8.7 of debian or to fix this error without uninstalling?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY

Comment: Please [edit here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/353501/edit) by adding the whole error message

Comment: Note that in `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, the `sudo` command affects only the `apt-get update` part.

Answer (score 1):

If your repository links in `/etc/apt` are stale, have a look at them and change them to more current links.

To ensure up-to-date public keys, use `aptitude` or `apt-get` to force an upgrade of all the `keyring` packages, especially `debian-keyring`.